# Different types of Duplicate question?

Tags: support, duplicates

I have recently noticed two types of questions marked as duplicate, the both have `[Duplicate]` in the title, and they both have something like this at the bottom:

[image]

However the **first** one has this at the top:

[image]

And no extra automatically added code at the top if you go into `Edit` view. And the **second** has this at the top:

[image]

And `Edit` view reveals this added code at the top:

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [How to download a youtube video via terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145558/how-to-download-a-youtube-video-via-terminal)


<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

So my question is this, what is the difference between the two Duplicate marked questions? Why does one have one thing added at the top with supposedly automated code, and other a cleaner look? Is the second one the old system or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the second one the old system or something?

Yes.

In 2013, changes were made to ["Close as duplicate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/270345). Presumably, the second question was closed before February 2013.

Related:

- [Two kinds of Duplicate closing are too confusing - suggestion for a possible fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181915/270345)